# Does grouping functions like start/stop and open/close violate the Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: java, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

For example:

```
class Engine {
    private EventExecutor executor;

    public void start() {
        executor.submit(...);
        executor.submit(...);
        //...
    }

    public void stop() {
       executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Submitting different events requires modifying `start`, but not `stop`. Changing how the executor terminates requires modfying `stop`, not `start`.

Those methods have two separate reasons for modification (submitting events and tuning termination), so should they be separated like the example below?

```
class Engine {
    private EventExecutor executor;
    private EngineStarter starter;
    private EngineStopper stopper;

    public void start() {
        starter.start(executor);
    }

    public void stop() {
        stopper.stop(executor);
    }
}

interface EngineStarter {
    void start(EventExecutor executor);
}

interface EngineStopper {
    void stop(EventExecutor executor);
}
```

Does the first example violate SRP? Should the behaviors be defined in a different class?

Comment: I think you are confused between SRP and [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). Your question makes much more sense to me if the question is about ISP instead.

Answer (score 3):

The Single Responsibility Principle is not violated as long as you have only one `start` and one `stop`. If you have to morph the behavior behind these methods, using interfaces like you did is the right way.

Now, in the first example, if your engine has to send various events when it starts, it's not a responsibility problem, but a strong coupling problem. The responsibility to send the events is still his, no violation here, but you create a strong coupling with the various events, and that can backfire when your code grows larger.

For that kind of system, using an Observer pattern is usually the best way. Objects will listen for your engine to start, and if it does, execute the right events themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The `Engine` class here may be mapped directly to the [canonical](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/srp.pdf) `Modem` example, where Robert Martin describes four methods having two distinct responsibilities.

> The `dial` and `hangup` functions manage the connection of the modem,
>   while the `send` and `recv` functions communicate data.

If we presume that `dial == start` and `hangup == stop`, then these represent one responsibility. (In terms of a software engine, we might call it the *life-cycle* responsibility.) Conversely, the events submitted would map to the `send` function, which is a different responsibility. This leads to the conclusion that `start` should be separated from any specific list of events, rather than separated from `stop`.

Finally, note that in Martin's conclusion, the `modem` implementation remains in one class, violating SRP; but each responsibility is represented by a different interface. This conforms to the Interface Segregation Principle, as @Steven commented. So you may wish the `engine` to implement both `life-cycle` and `event-submitter`.